# Angular - Component with Native View Encapsulation and Global CSS rules

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component with Native View Encapsulation

This means that every CSS rule use the shadow DOM to apply my rule only to the current component. But I have a component that every time I use it, I want to style  tag. How can I combine Native View Encapsulation with global CSS rules?

Comment: can you clarify your question ? do you want to avoid the use of ``encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`` and still be able to style your component with global style ?

Comment: Exactly! This is what i want

Comment: you can place the rule in the root `styles.css` file. personally i use `scss @includes`. write it once and import it wherever.

Answer (score 1):

You add the global stylesheet to the `styleUrls` value in the component so that it's allowed under those circumstances, like so:

`styleUrls: ['./products.component.css', '../app.component.css'],`